# wget messes up the html

Tags: linux, web, wget, ghost-blog

I am currently hosting a blog on Ghost CMS on my local machine and am creating a static site from the hosted site at localhost:2368 using wget. It works well but the only problem I am facing is that the "srcset" is messed

```
<img class="post-card-image" srcset="content/images/size/w300/2020/08/logo-1--1.svg 300w,
                   content/images/size/w600/2020/08/logo-1--1.svgg 600w,
                  content/images/size/w1000/2020/08/logo-1--1.svgvg 1000w,
                 content/images/size/w2000/2020/08/logo-1--1.svgsvg 2000w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 400px, 700px" loading="lazy" src="content/images/size/w600/2020/08/logo-1--1.svg" alt="Test">
```

Notice how the extension is messed up for the 600w, 100w and 2000w as svgg, svgvg, svgsvg. This prevents the image from loading. I need to manually fix the extensions in the HTML.

Saving the HTML using the browser at localhost:2368 has no such problem.
The same element when the HTML is saved using the browser

```
<img class="post-card-image" srcset="/content/images/size/w300/2020/08/logo-1--1.svg 300w,
                    /content/images/size/w600/2020/08/logo-1--1.svg 600w,
                    /content/images/size/w1000/2020/08/logo-1--1.svg 1000w,
                    /content/images/size/w2000/2020/08/logo-1--1.svg 2000w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 400px, 700px" loading="lazy" src="/content/images/size/w600/2020/08/logo-1--1.svg" alt="Test">
```

But this is not an option since I have to save everything recursively manually.

The wget command I am using is

```
from_url=localhost:2368
to_url=example.com
to_https=true
export_directory=dist

# Copy blog content
wget --recursive --page-requisites --no-host-directories --remote-encoding=utf-8 --directory-prefix=${export_directory} --adjust-extension --restrict-file-names=windows --timeout=30 --no-parent --convert-links ${from_url}/
```

Using wget 1.20.3
I have already tried it without the --remote-encoding flag

Comment: That is weird. Can you look at developer options in browser (F12 usually), and then construct the same request with `wget`? Can you also try `curl`? What does wireshark tell you? I guess it could be httpd sending the corrupted response in some cases?

Comment: This _might_ be a bug in Wget. I have an inkling, it is. Please report this on bug-wget@gnu.org, and we'll try and help you out. Likely a buffer size corruption.

Comment: In the interim  - how does CURL handle these?

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same thing, trying to scrape a Wordpress site.  The end of each comma-separated element in the srcset list was mangled *from the space onwards*, with extra characters replacing the space and condition.

I dug in to the source and found it was a problem with calculating the lengths of the individual URLs in the srcset - when converting the final files, the code skips over the URL it just converted based on the length of the URL it saw when parsing the element.  *But* parsing is performed *after* decoding escapes in the original URLs, so the skipped length may too short (because decoding may reduce the length of the URL).

I managed to patch it to work on my case by calculating the length of the re-escaped URL.  I posted a patch at

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2020-12/msg00021.html

Comment: Great! Will test at my end